# Good style in declaration of local variables

Tags: c#

I need to use variables `rbFileChoice.Checked` and `rbHandWriteChoice.Checked` in method `LookAtChoice`. But I can't take acces to them from this method. So I use global variables `rbFileIsChecked` and `rbHandWriteIsChecked` which declarated at Constructor of my Form object. 
Is that solving good style of programming? Do another manners to take an acces for private-variables consist?

```
public partial class fMainWindow : Form
{
    bool rbFileIsChecked;
    bool rbHandWriteIsChecked;
    public fMainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rbFileIsChecked = rbFileChoice.Checked;
        rbHandWriteIsChecked = rbHandWriteChoice.Checked;
        Thread threadLookForChoice = new Thread(LookAtChoice);
        threadLookForChoice.Start();

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Функция фонового потока. Следит за выбором пользователя. В случае выбора
    /// нового пункта, удаляет старые введенные значения.
    /// </summary>
    public static void LookAtChoice()
    {
        if (true)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: change `loval` to `local` variables in question.

Comment: Post some concrete code in order to say if this is good style or not. Generally speaking you should always define your variables scope as small as possible.

Comment: Why global variables? You should use a Property(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

Comment: Why don´t you simply use the value of the radio-buttons within your method instead of the local members?

Comment: HimBromBeere, I can't use radio-button's values because RadioButtons are private-objects in Form. I try to gain an acces by means of full name, like: MyForm.RadioButton1.Cheked. But I can't.

Comment: But your method is also within MyForm, isn´t it? So you should be able to access its private members. Btw.: is there any specific reason for the method to be static?

Comment: @HimBromBeere, thanks! I made method non-static and it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your coding a Form class and the above controls are radio-buttons - the Form is an object and its controls are its members (and not global variables), so it makes sense that they'll be available throughout the class.

Saying that, it is good practice (not necessarily in your case) is to refactor the business logic to a simple method. 
For example, creating a method that receive two boolean parameters (like the radio-button's `Check` property) and acts accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

why u r declaring global variable instead of u can directly use it in LookAtChoice() method intialize it by using 
rbFileChoice.Checked;
rbHandWriteChoice.Checked; Properties....

Comment: I try to gain an acces to properties of radio buutons. But it doesn't work. Compiler said "For unstatic method, field or properties link to the object are needed"

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access your radio button outside this form. you should declare its modifer to public or internal . 
internal variable can be access within the namespace but with  class object.
public variable can also be access outside the namespace but with  class object.